# C# Game Menu Form ( Username, Start, Exit )

Tags: c#, screen, adventure

i'm new to the programming went through few tutorials and sample projects and then started to create my own text based adventure game with some UI.

So what i'd like to achieve with the beginning of my project is, when user launches exe, i'd like to greet them with a username input screen with Start and Exit buttons and then close that form, launch a new form which i'll put in the game's main interface.

So, when i click the "Start" Button, it'll read the username from the textbox, save it to a string, close the form and launch a new form with also using the name screen in the game's main interface.

**My question is**, How can i link the start button from the below code to a new Form, also closing the current AUJFM_Login form, which will also be able to read the string username.

I have tried few things but after a few attempts, i just left it with the button functions. It's not much but here is the basics of it:

The Greeting screen will be called AUJFM_Login, and the main interface will be called AUJFM.

```
namespace AUJFM
{
  public partial class AUJFM_Login : Form
  {
      public AUJFM_Login()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          string UserName = nameBox.Text;
      }

      private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          Application.Exit();
      }
  }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Unclear what you are tying or what is going wrong.

Comment: Also agree that it's unclear what kind of answer you expect as you didn't ask a specific question.

Comment: The code above will be launched when the exe file executed. And when i click the 'btnStart' it will read the Username typed in the textbox, close the current form, create another new form which will also save the username input to a variable in the new form. So my question is, how is it possible for me to do that?

Comment: I am just guessing as it is unclear exactly what the question is… however if you have another form you want to launch when the user pressed the “Start” button then you need to show the next form and pass the string to it. Something like: `SecondForm nextForm = new SecondForm(userString);` then show the second form with `nextForm.Show();` Again just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the code below for the “Start” button click. I added a method to check the user name as it seems like sending an invalid user name to the next form is simply a waste of time. You will have to adjust this method to check for the valid users. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string userName = nameBox.Text;
  if (ValidUserName(userName)) {
    SecondForm nextForm = new SecondForm(userName);
    nextForm.Show();
    this.Hide();
  } else {
    // user name not valid
  }
}

private bool ValidUserName(String userName) {
  // logic to check if user name is valid
  return true;
}
```

Then in the second form constructor, change the signature to accept the user name string.

```
public SecondForm(string userName) {
  InitializeComponent();
  textBox1.Text = userName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form for the main window (Let's call it MainForm),
you can do:

```
MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
mainForm.Show();
```

The main window would then appear.
To close the login form, you could do

```
this.Hide();
```

Since closing the form from which the application runs would close the entire application.